# Looping through POST data to update it's value in a database

Tags: php, pdo

I have a table which i'm basically looping through to create a dynamic form based on the columns and data ie:

```
gameID -> 1
gameName -> my game name
gameTitle -> game title
```

This table will likely grow in the future so i'm generating the form dynamic i.e:

```
while ($row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){

    foreach($row as $key => $value ){

        echo "<div class='formlabel floatL'> $key </div> <div class='formfield floatL'><input type='text' name='$key' value='$value' size='100' /></div> <div class='clear'></div><br />";

    }

}
```

However i'm not sure how to loop through this form fields dynamically. I have this so far but not sure how to complete it:

```
if ($_POST["updatesettings"] <> ""){

        foreach($_POST as $key => $value ){

            // query
            $query = $db->prepare(" UPDATE `games` SET `settingValue`= :value  WHERE `settingCode` = :key LIMIT 0,1 ");


            // bind parameters - avoids SQL injection
            $query->bindValue(':value', stripslashes($value));

            // try... if not catch exception
            try {
                // run the query
                //$query->execute();

            }
            catch (PDOException $e){
            }

        }

}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/tags/pdo/info near bottom

Answer (score -1):

So it sounds like the problem is you might have some arbitrary value for `$key` so you don;t know how to get all of them.

I would suggest using array access notation in your form inputs such that you have a better way to know where to get your key data from.  The inoput might look like this:

```
<input type='text' name='keys[$key]' value='$value' size='100' />
```

This would group all these inputs together into `$_POST['keys']`.  So you could just loop through them like this:

```
foreach($_POST['keys'] as $key => $value) {
    // make DB update
}
```